# Angular momentum along a straight line with 2d velocity

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum

I have a stationary referance for $L = 0$, $L = \vec{r} \times m\vec{v}$ can be interpreted as an area of a paralelogram. The area is constant, since $base \times height = constant$.

[image]

However, is this also true, if $v$ has components in two dimensions?
[image]

The picture is more complicated now...

Comment: You can always rotate the axes in your second set of graphs so that the direction of $mv$ is parallel to the x'-axis and then it is the same as your first diagram. [Cross product](https://mathinsight.org/cross_product)

Comment: @Farcher Ahhh, that's true! But if there were two objects each with speed in two dimensions and they aren't collinear, would this also work? I don't see it...

Comment: Just consider $\vec r \times m\vec v$.